# Diferencias entre ReciclerView y ListView

Tags: android

Estoy desarollando una `app` en `android`. He integrado el `sdk de twitter`, y me ofrece 2 opciones de mostrar un timeline, por `ReciclerView` o por `ListView`.

> El problema es que no sé cual es la diferencia entre ambos y cual es
>   mas eficiente o mas apropiado de usar. O en que circustancias usar uno u otro.

Comment: Aquí tienes toda la información: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728651/recyclerview-vs-listview

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero no se inglés @Kiko_L

Comment: @AlbertoMier definitivamente el **RecyclerView es más eficiente es una versión mejorada de ListView**, agregué el texto de la documentación en español y también la respuesta traducida a español de "deneejela"

Answer (score 3):

El widget [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) es una versión más flexible y avanzada de [ListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html). Este widget es un contenedor para mostrar grandes conjuntos de datos que se pueden desplazar de manera muy eficiente al mantener una cantidad limitada de vistas. Usa el widget [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) cuando tengas conjuntos de datos cuyos elementos cambien en tiempo de ejecución sobre la base de la acción del usuario o los eventos de la red.

La clase  [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)simplifica la pantalla y la manipulación de grandes conjuntos de datos al proporcionar lo siguiente:

> - Administradores de diseño para el posicionamiento de elementos.
> - Animaciones predeterminadas para las operaciones comunes con elementos, como quitar o agregar elementos.

También tienes la flexibilidad para definir administradores de diseño personalizados y animaciones para los widgets  [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tomado de  la [documentación Android](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)

---

La clase [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) simplifica la pantalla y la manipulación de grandes conjuntos de datos al proporcionar lo siguiente:

Administradores de diseño para el posicionamiento de elementos
Animaciones predeterminadas para las operaciones comunes con elementos, como quitar o agregar elementos
También tienes la flexibilidad para definir administradores de diseño personalizados y animaciones para los widgets RecyclerView.

[RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) se creó como una mejora de [ListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html), así que sí, puede crear una lista adjunta con control [ListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html), pero usar [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)es más fácil ya que:

> - Reutiliza las celdas mientras se desplaza hacia arriba / abajo; esto es posible implementando View Holder en el adaptador listView, pero
>     era una cosa opcional, mientras que en RecycleView es la forma
>     predeterminada de escribir el adaptador.
> - Desacopla la lista de su contenedor, por lo que puede poner elementos de lista fácilmente en tiempo de ejecución en los diferentes
>     contenedores (linearLayout, gridLayout) con la configuración de
>     LayoutManager.

Ejemplo:

```
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
//or
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));
```

> - Anima acciones de lista comunes: las animaciones se desacoplan y se delegan en ItemAnimator.

Hay más sobre [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html), pero creo que estos puntos son los principales.

**Entonces, para concluir, [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) es un control más flexible para manejar los "datos de lista" que sigue los patrones de delegación de preocupaciones y deja para sí solo una tarea: reciclar elementos.**

Tomado de la [respuesta de @daneejela](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728651/recyclerview-vs-listview)

Answer (score 1):

La ventaja principal de RecyclerView sobre ListView es que es mucho más eficiente a la hora de mostrar gran cantidad de datos. Eso es así porque "recicla" las vistas que no están en pantalla para cargar nuevos datos en ellas cuando haces *scroll*.

Aparte de eso es más flexible, te ofrece efectos y permite tocar más el diseño de los elementos y de la propia lista, es más sencillo manejar el click sobre elementos...

Como desventaja está que, al principio, es algo más complejo de implementar (en parte por el patrón de viewholder), pero una vez comprendes para qué es cada cosa lo preferirás.

Sobre todo si estás empezando, prueba las dos opciones, carga muchos datos y prueba el tema de lag en el scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Además de todas las respuestas anteriores, una de las implementaciones que permite RecyclerView frente a ListView es que el primero permite alojarse en un contenedorr padre con scroll mientras que el segundo no. A veces por nuestra lógica de negocio necesitamos de un Activity o fragment que contenga scroll por diversos motivos y en ese caso si usamos un ListView este se "bloqueará" no permitiéndote hacer scroll dentro de él. Yo perssonalmente uso ListView para dar formato a spinners y en algunos casos donde el modelo tiene pocos datos (futuros items) y la lógica de negocio lo permite.

Esta respuesta está basada en mi experiencia personal.